# Google Chrome - doing very abnormal on boot to go to kiosk mode

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, windows-8.1, kiosk

I am launching Google chrome via regedit on system boot (Windows 8.1 64-bit).

```
chrome.exe --kiosk <url>
```

Google Chrome is latest version up-to date and windows operating system is also up-to date.

But when the system boot and whole day the Google Chrome does not run properly it start from left with some gape instead full kiosk mode. How to fix this BUG please? (see the screen-shot the desktop icons are exposed normally it should not)

Comment: why u added link i canhazip?its the link which replies public ip address,is the link related to the question?

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303: That's clearly the URL he's using while launching Chrome.

Comment: If you launch Chrome in kiosk mode from the command line does it open up properly then, or is this behaviour limited only to Chrome being launched at startup? Also, which registry key did you edit?

Comment: command line does it properly. this is the behavious limited only to chrome being launched at startup. i used : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run